# Insert data in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I am in the process of developing a we app with blazor. I try to insert data from a table from the razor page to the database, but it does not work, when I clicking the InsertProduct button. Is there anyone can help me with this?
Below is my code:

Code:

```
    <select @bind="ClientId" name="ClientId" id="ClientId" class="form-control" style="width: auto; float: right">
        <option selected disabled="">-- Select Client --</option>
        @foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            <option id="@client.Id" name="@client.Name" value="@client.Id">@client.Id- @client.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
<form>
    <InputFile OnChange="ReadExcel"  />   
    <br /><br />    
</form>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:100px" @onclick="InsertProduct"><i class="fa fa-user-save"></i>Indsert</button>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Serienumber</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Fee</th>
            <th>ClientId</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var product in products)
        {
            <tr>                
                <td>@product.Serienumber</td>
                <td>@product.Name</td>
                <td>@product.Type</td>
                <td>@product.Fee</td>
            <td>
                <select @bind="ClientId" class="form-control" style="width: auto">
                    
                    @foreach (var client in clients)
                    {
                        <option id="@client.Id" name="@client.Name" value="@client.Id">@client.Id</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
protected void InsertProduct() 
{ bool isSaved = data.AddProdukt(product); 
  if (isSaved)   { product = new ProductModel(); } 
}
```

And from ClientData:

```
public bool InsertProduct(ProductModel product) 
{ _db.Product.Add(product); 
  int rowAffected = _db.SaveChanges(); 
  if (rowAffected > 0) { return true; } 
  return false; 
}
```

```
protected void ReadExcel()
{
    products = data.ReadExcel();
}
```

Comment: This code does not show the right sections.  You should show the code of the insert method.  From what I can see, maybe you should cut the `type=submit` on your button, since it doesn't seem to be in a form.

Comment: ` @ Bennyboy1973. This is the code of the insert method:

    protected void InsertProduct()
    {
        bool isSaved = data.AddProdukt(product);
        if (isSaved)
        {
            product = new ProductModel();
        }
    }

And from ClientData:

 public bool InsertProduct(ProductModel product)
        {
            _db.Product.Add(product);
            int rowAffected = _db.SaveChanges();

            if (rowAffected > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }`

Comment: @AKS Please add the code to the Question, not as a comment - it's almost impossible to read.

Comment: @AKS have you set breakpoints to see if `data.AddProdukt` is ever reached?

Comment: @MrC aka Shun Curtis. Thanks for your note.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I have used similar code with Client Insert with InputText and it works fine.

Comment: Did you try removing the `submit` flag from the button?

Comment: @AKS - "It does not work" isn't very informative.  You need to run your application in debug mode to step through the code.  Your Save function saves `Product` but I can't see where product comes from (I may of course be blind!).   `Product` could be empty, who knows!

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - Yes I have removed it.

Comment: @ MrC aka Shaun Curtis - The data is from where I upload an excel file and then have to be inserted into the Product table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's make a checklist.  Here are (off the top of my head) the things you should check for.  Use breakpoints to figure out the case.

- The event isn't firing at all
- The insert code isn't correct
- You are missing some database issue, like context.SaveChanges() is missing
- It's working, but the UI isn't updating

Set breakpoints, step through your code, and identify the exact line where you aren't getting the behavior you expect.

You are still missing important code.  I don't see anywhere that `public bool InsertProduct(ProductModel product)` gets called.

Comment: @ Bennyboy1973 - I have reviewed the codes and there is no error. But I think there is something with @bind to be connected with the table, because when I use bind with <input \> it works and the dates are inserted into DB.